# Git can't clone project via ssh Deployer

Tags: php, git, ssh, php-deployer

I'm using Deployer to clone a project onto a server, but despite setting up the deploy key, for some reason cloning via SSH is failing:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Steps I've taken:

1. Generate new key on the server where I'm cloning my project: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`, my key file is in this forat: `form_simple_id_rsa` and of course the pub version too.
2. Did `eval` and added the key: `ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/form_simple_id_rsa`
3. Tested the connection and all good here.
4. Added the `form_simple_id_rsa.pub` key to my repository as a deploy key, the repo owner isn't my account, I'm a collab on this repo, but the server's key is linked to the project so it should be able to clone.
5. Setup deployer in my project to use my host, port, and the new key I made (because there are a few keys), etc:

```php
host('project')
    ->port(myport)
    ->identityFile('~/.ssh/form_simple_id_rsa')
    ->stage('production')
    ->set('repository', 'git@github.com:company/project.git')
    ->user('root')
    ->set('deploy_path', '/var/www/path');
```

6. Tried deploying, get an exit code with an error:

```
Exit Code: 128(Invalid exit argument)
```

Saying that the `ssh -A -tt` command failed.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a DEployer version issue ([as in here](https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/issues/1197)), I would try:

- generating and testing a key without a passphrase (to avoid the `ssh-add step`, making sure there is no passphrase required)
- generating a key using `-m PEM`, to use the old PEM format instead of the new OPENSSH one, in case it has any effect